# Left Join that always includes null records

Tags: sql, oracle, join, null, left-join

I'm using `Oracle 11gR2` and I am trying to write a query that returns address data from two tables, `CUSTOMERS` and `LOCATIONS`.  A given customer may (or may not) have different locations, each with their own address.

I would like to return the address for every customer, and all their locations. For example, if the tables contained data like:

```
CUSTOMERS
CUSTOMER_ID    ADDRESS
    1         "New York"
    2         "California"
```

LOCATIONS
CUSTOMER_ID   LOCATION_ID    ADDRESS
    1             1        "New Jersey"

Then I want the results to look like:

```
CUSTOMER_ID    LOCATION_ID    ADDRESS
   1                         "New York"
   1                1       "New Jersey"
   2                        "California"
```

My first thought was something like this:

```
SELECT 
 CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID,
 LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID,
 NVL(LOCATIONS.ADDRESS,CUSTOMERS.ADDRESS) ADDRESS
FROM
CUSTOMERS
 LEFT JOIN
LOCATIONS ON (CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID=LOCATIONS.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

The problem with that is that when a customer does have locations, it does not return a row with null values for location data, so I don't get a row with the address in the `CUSTOMERS` table.  It gives me something like this:

```
CUSTOMER_ID    LOCATION_ID    ADDRESS
   1                1       "New Jersey"
   2                        "California"
```

It's missing the `New York` address for `customer 1`.  I tried this...

```
SELECT 
 CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID,
 LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID,
 NVL(LOCATIONS.ADDRESS,CUSTOMERS.ADDRESS) ADDRESS
FROM
CUSTOMERS
 LEFT JOIN
LOCATIONS ON (CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID=LOCATIONS.CUSTOMER_ID OR LOCATIONS.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL)
```

But it gave me the same results as the first query.  Is there a way to return a null record for the second table even when there is a match on the join condition?

Comment: try a full outer join on both customerID and address

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need a join here at all:

```
SELECT  customer_id, NULL AS location_id, address
FROM    customers
UNION ALL
SELECT  customer_id, location_id, address
FROM    locations
```

Comment: Doh.  I had a feeling I was missing something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mike: you're welcome. If it was helpful, please don't forget to upvote this post and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a full outer join. For example:

```
SELECT    
CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID,   
LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID,   
NVL(LOCATIONS.ADDRESS,CUSTOMERS.ADDRESS) ADDRESS             
FROM  CUSTOMERS   
  FULL OUTER JOIN  LOCATIONS ON (CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID=LOCATIONS.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

Comment: This gives the same results as my first query (there are no records in LOCATIONS without a matching customer in CUSTOMERS).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the two tables even when there is a non match, you will need to use `IS NULL` on your joined columns.

For example.

```
Table 1:
CustomerID
CustomerName
```

.

```
Table 2:
CustomerID
CustomerEmail
```

.

```
Select,
CustomerID,
CustomerName,
ISNULL (CustomerEmail, NULL) AS CustomerEmail


FROM table1

LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.CustomerID = table2.CustomerID
```

This wil bring back results with `NULL`